# Can't execute my script with an option

Tags: bash

whenever I try to use one option i implemented in my script i receive this message.

```
$ sh ss9.sh -d u1
mv: invalid option -- 'd'
```

I have no idea what I've done wrong in my script.

```
#!/bin/bash
for dir in "$@"
do
mv "$dir"/* /tmp
done

if [ $# -lt 1 ] ; then
echo "ERROR: no argument"
exit 1  # pas 0
else
case $# in
-d) mv -R $dir/* /tmp        
   ;;
-x) find -executable -type f | xargs mv -t "$dir"/* /tmp
   ;;
esac
fi
```

Comment: it should be `case $1 in -d ) ...` Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

The isse is that the first loop iterates over the arguments of your script and expects them to be directories. But `-d` is not a directory. However, `mv` tries to process it as one and that does fail.

A solution could be to first check for parameters (like `-d`) and then pass the remaining arguments to the for loop.

Answer (score 0):

Your script got as arguments: `-d u1`.

```
for dir in "$@"   #processing -d u1
do
mv "$dir"/* /tmp  # here will get: mv -d/* /tmp
done
```

You should process the switches at the start. For the helper, see `getopt`.

Answer (score 0):

The first loop in your script passes each argument in turn to a `mv` command, including any intended to be options.  The error you see is emitted when the shell tries to execute the command

```
mv -d/* /tmp
```

If you want your script to support options as well as non-option arguments, then you need to distinguish between them.

Answer (score 0):

You can reorder the logic of your script to help address each of your modes of operation without any one option causing problems with the other. One way of doing this is to process and respond to all input in your `case` statement. Example:

```
#!/bin/bash

[ -n "$1" ] || {
    echo "Error: insufficient input. usage: ${0##*/} -d -x dirname"
    exit 1
}

case "$1" in
    -d )
        mv -R $dir/* /tmp
        ;;
    -x )
        find -executable -type f | xargs mv -t "$dir"/* /tmp
        ;;
    *  )
        for dir in "$@"; do
            [ -e "$dir" ] && mv "$dir"/* /tmp
        done
        ;;
esac

exit 0
```

Here, you test you have input, if not provide usage and exit. If there is input, then if `-d` respond with a `mv`, if `-x` respond with your `find`, and then finally if nothing else matches, use the `default` case statement to **test** if your input is a file/dir that exists, and if so, then `mv`. That is one way of reordering. (Note: I used your commands without testing further :)